# Integration Testing File Uploads

Tags: php, laravel, integration-testing

I am currently developing an MVC website with some form functionality. As part of the form, users can choose to upload a file. The I've written the code for this and it is working perfectly but my issue comes from trying to write automated tests to ensure I don't break anything with future refactors.

I have read through the laravel documentation for file uploads and attempted to replicate this but get an failure when asserting that the file exists. The form is optional but there is some data that is required to be sent with it.

TestFile

```
 public function testDirect_FormPassesWithFile() 
    {
        Storage::fake('local');
        $file = UploadedFile::fake()->create('document.pdf');
        $response = $this->post('/direct', $this->data());
        $response->assertSessionHasNoErrors();
        Storage::disk('local')->assertExists($file->hashName());
        $response->assertStatus(302);
        $this->assertCount(1, QuickQuote::all()); 
    }

 private function data() 
    { 
        return [
            'name' => $this->faker->name,
            'email' => $this->faker->email,
            'phone' =>'07718285557',
            'risk' => $this->faker->address,
            'rebuild' => $this->faker->numberBetween($min = 500000, $max = 1000000),
            'startdate' => '2019-09-01',
            'currentpremium' => $this->faker->numberBetween($min = 100, $max = 1000),
            'file' => 'document.pdf',
            '_token' => csrf_token()
        ];
    }
```

Controller

```
 public function store(StoreQuickQuote $request)
    {
        $validated = $request->validated();

        //Code entered if there are any files uploaded
        if ($request->file('file')) {
            //loop through each file and store, saving path to an array
            $files = array();
            foreach($request->file('file') as $file) {
                $path = $file->store('uploads'); 
                array_push($files, $path);
            }
            //Turn the array into json and then insert into the validated data
            $filenames = json_encode($files);
            $merged = array_merge($validated, ['file' => $filenames]);

            $quick_quote = QuickQuote::create($merged);
        }

        //No files so just store
        $quick_quote = QuickQuote::create($validated);

        return redirect('/direct')->with('success', 'Thanks! We\'ll Be In Touch.');
    }
```

Validation Request

```
 public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'name' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'phone' => 'required',
            'risk' => 'required',
            'rebuild' => 'required',
            'startdate' => 'required',
            'currentpremium' => 'present',
            'file' => 'nullable'
        ];
    }
```

Form Input

```
<input type="file" id="file" name="file[]" multiple>
```

My output is always

```
There was 1 failure:

1) Tests\Feature\DirectTest::testDirect_FormPassesWithFile
Unable to find a file at path [mJ4jQ2hmxW6uMMPEneUVS6O4bZziuuTT5kq2NFVS.pdf].
Failed asserting that false is true.
```

I'm not too sure where I am going so any tips would be great.

Thanks

Comment: You are storing the files in the folder `uploads`, so shouldn't it be `Storage::disk('local')->assertExists("uploads/{$file->hashName()}");`

Comment: Sadly, ```Storage::disk('local')->assertExists("uploads/{$file->hashName()}");``` gives the same result.

Comment: Can you try sending the actual file with the post request instead of just `'file' => 'document.pdf'`, the hashName might be different because of this.

Comment: ```$file = UploadedFile::fake()->create('document.pdf');
$response = $this->post('/direct', array_merge($this->data(), ['file' => $file]));
```

I've turned off exception handling and am getting 
```FatalThrowableError: Call to a member function store() on string
```

Comment: You are looping through `$request->file('file')` so you need to send it as an array: `array_merge($this->data(), ['file' => [$file]])`

Comment: That gives me ErrorException: Array to string conversion

Comment: On which line does it throw this execption?

Comment: It was line 38 of the controller, which shouldn't be hit if there is a file. I've fixed that by wrapping it in an else but now it just fails with the usual message rather than throwing an error.

Comment: If the file is correctly saved you should be able to find it in  `storage/framework/testing/local/uploads`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing the name of the file in as a string in the POST data, but this is incorrect. You need to post the file itself to the test framework. You can do this with the `call` method. The 5th parameter is for posted files.

```
$this->call('POST', route('route.to.test'), $params, [], compact('file'))
```